# How to connect Node.js to MySQL Workbench

Tags: database, connectivity

Error:

> Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

And piece of code used to connect is:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
require("dotenv").config();

var pool = mysql.createConnection({   connectionLimit: 10,   host:
process.env.DB_HOST,   user: process.env.DB_USER,   password:
process.env.DB_PASSWORD,   database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,   port:
process.env.DB_PORT,   multipleStatements: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to set the connection parameters in `.env` file. You are using `dotenv`.
Just add

```
DB_USER=<username>
DB_PASSWORD=<password>
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
```

Don't forget to change `<username>` and `<password>` to your username and password.

Suggest removing `Workbench` from the question title. You are connectin to the server.

Comment: thank you for your input, I did the same as you mentioned in the .env file but all I do, comes up with the same error. It seems that may be there is an authentication issue, so database doesnt allow the connection???

Comment: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: @Amjad It looks like username and password are not passed to mysql. Try to console.log process.env.DB_USER and process.env.DB_PASSWORD and see if they are correct.

Comment: thank you for the help. Actually problem been solved now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not setting the environment variables `DB_USER` and `DB_PASSWORD`

You should set the environment variables before running your script. Please make sure to set the actual values.

```
export DB_USER=username 
export DB_PASSWORD=password
export DB_HOST=localhost
export DB_PORT=3306
node script.js
```

script.js

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
require("dotenv").config();

var pool = mysql.createConnection({
  connectionLimit: 10, host:
    process.env.DB_HOST, 
    user: process.env.DB_USER, 
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD, 
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE, 
    port: process.env.DB_PORT, 
    multipleStatements: true
});

console.log('process.env.DB_HOST: ', process.env.DB_HOST)
console.log('process.env.DB_USER: ', process.env.DB_USER)
console.log('process.env.DB_PASSWORD: ', process.env.DB_PASSWORD)
console.log('process.env.DB_DATABASE: ', process.env.DB_DATABASE)
console.log('process.env.DB_PORT: ', process.env.DB_PORT)
```

To check whether your credentials are correct,  you could check using the mysql command. Please run this command in the terminal with your correct username and password.

`mysql -u username -p password`

Comment: thank you for your input. Actually I have set environment variable but when I run the script, it shows the above error as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: can you log the environment variables.

Comment: DB_HOST = 'localhost'
DB_USER = 'root'
DB_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
DB_DATABASE = 'meal_sharing_db'
DB_PORT = '3306'

Comment: Oh I see, but when I log these variables, it says undefined. And where I should run "mysql -u username -p password" this? dont have any idea :) help needed

Comment: Run it on the terminal. I think you are setting environment variables but dot.env making it undefined. Either remove `require("dotenv").config()` or add a `.env` file

Comment: yes I have already added up a .env file. Actually I am a beginner, dont know much by the way and tried hard to find a solution on youtube and through google.

Comment: when I run this 'mysql -u username -p password' command then its shows this: 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -u username -p password



Enter password: ***********

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: when you run the command, change the `username` and `password` to your credentials. your main problem is that the environment variables are not set.